# Use tidyr and dplyr to extract correlations of several pairs of variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the results of two different types of factor analysis (oblimin and varimax) attached to my dataset. I'd like to correlate - and perhaps also plot - the scores from the first factor from the oblimin rotation with the scores from  first factor from the varimax rotation and then the second factors from both, etc.  Because I'd like to visualize the effects of the different types of the rotations.  My data looks as it does below. Somehow I feel like I should be able to end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
Variable | Oblimin Score | Varimax Score
h        | 0.23          | 0.12
h        | -1            | -.87
i        | 0.2           | 0.3
i        | 0.5           | 0.4
...      | ...           | ...
```

The code that provides a sample data frame is below.   Currently, I am ending with an error message that there are duplicate identifiers. I tried the solution to provide a unique id number as below with this in the chain  - mutate(id=sequence(n()))%>% - but it prodcues a dataframe where the oblimin and the varimax scores are on alternating rows.

```
#libraries
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#fake data
h.varimax<-rnorm(1000)
h.oblimin<-rnorm(1000)
i.varimax<-rnorm(1000)
i.oblimin<-rnorm(1000)
df<-data.frame(h.varimax, h.oblimin, i.varimax, i.oblimin)
#restructuring
df%>%
#this is necessary in my code, not in the sample data code though
select(contains('varimax'), contains('oblimin'))%>%
#wide to long
gather(variable, value) %>%
#split the variable 'variable' so that I have one variable with two values,     
#h or i.  I want to correlate the oblimin and the varimax scores for the i 
#variables and the oblimin and the varimax scores for the h variables     
separate(variable, into=c('factor', 'method')) %>%
#This seems necessary to spread the method variable back into two columns     
spread(method, value)
```

Comment: Did you run that code? It does not work. Perhaps you can post the `dput` of the final input data frame?

Comment: addressed.  There was a comment code missing.

Comment: that is the problem I am trying to solve!!!

Comment: Save the result of everything up to that `separate` statement into a data frame - call it `ndf`. Then, inspect `ndf[c(2001, 2002), ]` for example. You notice, there are duplicate values for `method`. `spread` won't deal with them.

Comment: Does this work for you? ` %>% mutate(id = rep(1:2000, 2)) %>% spread(method, value)`

Comment: Yes! Thanks! That does it.